How to get localized routes to work in Nuxt 3.14 with @nuxt/i18n
I'm trying to get localized routes to work in Nuxt 3.14.
I have setup Nuxt and added the required module @nuxt/i18n v9 to my project and in addition, as described in the docs, added a i18n.config.ts to it.
In my nuxt.config.ts I've added the i18n object like so:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ... // other options
    i18n: {
        vueI18n: './i18n.config.ts'
    }
})

In the i18n.config.ts I've added the following options:
export default defineI18nConfig({
    legacy: false,
    locale: 'de',
    defaultLocale: 'de,
    globalInjection: true,
    messages: {
        de,
        en
    },
    customRoutes: 'config' // <<<< required for localized routes
    pages: {               // <<<< Mapping for the localized routes, I guess
        about: {
            de: 'ueber-uns',
            en: 'about-us'
        }
    },
    experimental: {
        scanPageMeta: true,
    },
})

Then in the pages/[localized]/about.vue file I'm doing the following:
<template>localized about content</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
    defineI18nRoute: ({
        paths: {
            de: '/de/uber-uns',
            en: '/en/about-us'
        }
     })
 </script>

However, that doesn't work and I don't know how to proceed with this.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

First I think you should define a strategy in your config for example strategy: "prefix_and_default". Second you should remove the locale from route definition and have only de: '/uber-uns'.
